# React JS Hooks - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Card from "./Card"

import joker from "../../assets/joker.png"
import goalie from "../../assets/goalie.png"
import defender from "../../assets/defender.png"
import midfielder from "../../assets/midfielder.png"
import attacker from "../../assets/attacker.png"

const CardsBoard = () => {

  const deckLimits = {
    joker: 4, goalkeepers: 12, defenders: 12, midfielders: 12, attackers: 12
  };

  const [ratingObj, setRatingObj] = useState({});
  const [visible1, setVisible1 ] = useState(false);
  const [visible2, setVisible2 ] = useState(false);
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState([]);
  const [deck1, setDeck1] = useState([]);
  const [deck2, setDeck2] = useState([]);
  const [currCardPl1, setCurrCardPl1] = useState({});
  const [currCardPl2, setCurrCardPl2] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    generateDeck();
    distributeCards();
  }, [deck]);


  const startGame = () => {
    //reset decks
    setDeck([]);
    setDeck1([]);x
    setDeck2([]);

    //generate the card’s values
    generateDeck();
    if (deck.length > 0) {
      distributeCards();

      if (currCardPl1 != undefined){
        console.log(currCardPl1);
        //unMask ratings of Player 1
        setVisible1(true);
        setVisible2(false);
      }
    }
  };

  const distributeCards = () => {
      //randomize the deck
      deck.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

      //distribute 26 cards at random when the game start
      const splitDeck1 = deck.slice(0, 26);
      const splitDeck2 = deck.slice(26, 52);
      //add this card to the deck
      splitDeck1.map((card) => {
        setDeck1(deck1 => [...deck1, card]);
      });
      //add this card to the deck
      splitDeck2.map((card) => {
        setDeck2(deck2 => [...deck2, card]);
      });
      
      //queue the first card to Player 1
      setCurrCardPl1(deck1[0]);      
      //queue the first card to Player 2
      setCurrCardPl2(deck2[0]);      
  };

  const generateDeck = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.joker; i++) {
      generateCard('joker');
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.goalkeepers; i++) {
      generateCard('goalkeeper');
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.defenders; i++) {
      generateCard('defender');
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.midfielders; i++) {
      generateCard('midfielder');
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < deckLimits.attackers; i++) {
      generateCard('attacker');
    };
  }

  const generateCard = item => {
    const card = {
      player: 0,
      image: getImage(item),
      title: item.toUpperCase(),
      ratings: [
        { title: "Handling", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Reflexes", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Defending", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Strength", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Passing", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Flair", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Finishing", rating: "99" },
        { title: "Composure", rating: "99" },
      ],
    }

    //add this card to the deck
    setDeck(deck => [...deck, card]);
  }

  const getImage = item => {
    switch (item) {
      case "joker":
          return joker;
      case "goalkeeper":
          return goalie;
      case "defender":
          return defender;
      case "midfielder":
          return midfielder;
      case "attacker":
          return attacker;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid justify-content-center">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div>
            <h4>Player 1</h4>
          </div>
          <Card
            cardInfo={currCardPl1}
            showRatings={visible1}
            onClick={ratingObj => setRatingObj(ratingObj)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h4>Player 2</h4>
          <Card
            cardInfo={currCardPl2}
            showRatings={visible2}
            onClick={ratingObj => setRatingObj(ratingObj)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row top-buffer">
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
          <button
            id="startGameBtn"
            name="StartGameButton"
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            onClick={() => startGame()}
          >
            START GAME
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardsBoard
```

And I am getting the error:-

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

I am suspecting it has to do something with the Submit button (onClick) which is calling the setState multiple times, however I cannot seem to fix the problem.

So I have the following questions :-

1. How can I fix the onClick()?
2. I would like to click on the Start Game button, and trigger `generateDeck();` and `distributeCards();` so that I get the deck, deck1 and deck2 filled up.  Is there a way to do it?  At the moment I have created a `useEffect()` which is dependant on the deck being filled up, is that the correct way to doing it with hooks?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Once you call `generateDeck` it will change `deck` which will trigger an infinite loop in `useEffect`. See in `generateCard`.

Comment: Is there a reason to add `deck` to the `useEffect` dependencies?  do you want the deck updated *only* on page load?  if so, maybe that dependency list should be `[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `deck` as a dependency in your `useEffect` hook. That means `generateDeck` will run every time the deck is updated. However, `generateDeck` calls `generateCard`, which calls `setDeck`. That causes `deck` to change, which means you're stuck in a sort of infinite loop. You should tie `generateDeck` to the onClick handler or some other event which will not be triggered by `deck` changing.

Also, be careful with this:

```
deck.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
```

Calling `sort` will mutate your state directly, which is something you should avoid in React. Try something like `setDeck(d=>[...d].sort(/* Your sorting function here */))` instead.

Comment: How can I tie the generateDeck() useEffect on the onClick handler?

Comment: Also removing the dependency on deck[] in the useEffect() is causing me to click the Start Game button 3 times to get data.  Is it possible to be clicked once and load the decks correctly?

Comment: If you have the generateDeck function as an onClick handler, you won't need it in useEffect. As for needing to click the button more than once, it might have to do with the fact that `generateDeck` doesn't distribute the cards unless the deck's length is greater than 0. You might have to rethink the order of those function calls and what triggers them

Comment: Ok Danilo I will give you the answer.  I will have to rip my code apart, and build it again one step at a time.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setDeck()` in `distrubuteCards` and in your `useEffect` hook, you call again the `distributeCards`

```
  const distributeCards = () => {
  // bla bla
       setDeck(deck => [...deck, card]);
  }
```

Which results in calling the hook all the time.

```
useEffect(() => {
    generateDeck();
    distributeCards();
  }, [deck]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deck.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```

You have a problem here.
Save it inside a variable. Otherwise you update the state all the time it's called.